# Can someone explain the prediction equation for support vector regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to implement my own SVR code from scratch to understand the theory in depth. Referring to Equation (19) in Smola, *A Tutorial in support vector regression*. Predictions are found by.[image]

1. Am i right in saying that l is the length of the alpha's (that are >0) found?
2. For the kernel function, k(xi,x) what is the difference between the xi and x?
   is xi the examples that correspond to the support vectors in the training data set?

```py
prediction = np.zeros((test_size,1))
for i in range(test_size):
    s = 0
    for a,sv in zip(alpha, sv_x):
        s += a.T * gaussian_kernel(test_data[i],sv)
    prediction[i] = s
```

For this code have not included the bias yet, here alpha are the lagrange multipliers greater than 0 (or tolerance) and sv_x are the examples that correspond to each alpha from the training set. 
Running this code the predictions are way off from the y_test for verification.

3. Is my code in finding the predictions correct?

Comment: as far as i know, x is the subject you a re making prediciton for and x_i is every other subject, however some of the alphas are 0 (those that are not support vectors) so in practice you only care about x_i, that are support vectors

Comment: so are x_i the examples from the training set or the test set?

Comment: training, that is your kernel matrix. But i hope somebody more knowledgeable than me will give you a better answer